# searching for records in mysql using or - and - not in query

Tags: mysql

I think I am getting turned around when looking at this.  I am trying to get all patron records relating to transactions that have a transaction item with one of a number of ids (1 or 2) as well as transaction items with other ids (3 or 4) but not with transaction items with other ids (5 or 6)

The structure is:

=patron=

- id
- fname
- lname
- email
- phone

=trans=

- id
- id_org
- id_patron

=trans_item=

- id
- id_trans
- id_perf

I was trying the following:

```
SELECT
    patron.email,
    patron.fname,
    patron.lname,
    patron.phone
FROM
    trans_item,
    trans,
    patron
WHERE
    trans_item.id_perf IN (1,2)
        AND
    trans_item.id_perf IN (3,4)
        AND
    trans_item.id_perf NOT IN (5,6)
        AND
    trans_item.id_trans = trans.id
        AND
    trans.id_org = 1
        AND
    trans.id_patron = patron.id
GROUP BY
    patron.id
ORDER BY
    patron.email DESC,
    patron.phone DESC
```

I'm aware that saying the id needs to be 2 AND 4 is always going to return nothing but I need to have it as if id is in (1,2) AND (3,4) so it can be 1 or 2 but also needs to be in 3 or 4

For Clarity:
I am trying to get patrons who have gone to performance 1 OR 2 and 3 OR 4 but NOT 5 OR 6

Comment: `trans_item.id_perf IN (1,2) AND trans_item.id_perf IN (3,4)` always evaluates as `FALSE` and the query does not return any rows.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with `group by` and `having`.  The basic idea is:

```
select ti.id_trans
from trans_item ti
group by ti.id_trans
having sum(ti.id_perf in (1, 2)) > 0 and
       sum(ti.id_perf in (3, 4)) > 0 and
       sum(ti.id_perf in (5, 6)) = 0;
```

Each condition in the `having` clause checks a row for the particular ids.  The `> 0` means they exist for transaction.  The `= 0` means they do not.

If you want additional columns from other tables, you can join back to this result set.

Comment: I've tried this but keep getting an error that it is unrecognised

Comment: @AlanDoolan . . . What is unrecognized?

Comment: Actually, I may be misunderstanding this.  Is this a sub search within the search that already exists or are you suggesting adding the "group by" to the existing search?

Comment: @AlanDoolan . . . I am suggesting running this query to find the transactions that meet the criteria that you state in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have a solution.  If I combine the ids for all perfs and group all results by the trans_item.id I can get a list that has duplicates.  I then convert them into a php multidimensional array and exclude / include based on the ids for each requirement finding the duplicates that way.  Any other suggestions are welcome